# in python , need to save all results, not last result only

Tags: python, string, import, frequency, python-re

this is working code for counting words in file but the 
problem is (result.csv) contain only last result, not all results.

what should be the code look like after fixing ?

Thanks

```
import re
import string

frequency = {}


out_filename = "result.csv"
headers = "word,requency \n"

document_text = open('joined.xml', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', text_string)


for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print(words, frequency[words])

with open(out_filename, "w") as fw:
  fw.write(headers)
  fw.write(words + ", " + str(frequency[words]) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over all the word-frequency pairs and write each to a separate line.

```
with open(out_filename, "w") as fw:
  fw.write(headers)
  for word, freq in frequency.items():
      fw.write(word + ", " + str(freq) + "\n")
```